# Input string was not in a correct format #2

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, double

```
double temp;
temp = (double)Convert.ToDouble("1234.5678");
```

Hey Lads and Ladies, I can't for the life of me figure out why the above line isn't working. The above line gives me a runtime error that says;

> An unhandled exception of type
>   System.FormatException occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Input string
>   was not in a correct format.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As far as I know the `Convert` methods use the current locale to do such conversions. In this case I'd guess your current locale would expect a comma as decimal point. Try to set the current locale for your application or the conversion to some language/country where dots are used (e.g. en_US). The method should provide a second optional parameter to provide a IFormatProvider as an alternative solution.

Answer (score 25):

In order to [convert string to double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yd1h1be.aspx) without an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type System.FormatException occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

make it culture-insensitive by providing second parameter value [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx), for example:

```
double.Parse("1234.5678", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 12):

first solution (as mentioned in other posts):

```
double temp = double.Parse("1234.5678", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

second solution - make it default to current thread:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
double temp = double.Parse("1234.5678");
```

third solution - make it default to block of code:

```
var prevCurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
...
double temp = double.Parse("1234.5678");
...
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = prevCurrentCulture;
```

Answer (score 5):

You may be somehow using a european local.  In some countries the . and , in numbers is reversed.

Answer (score 4):

Hi as Mario says you must parse it taking into account the regional settings.

```
double temp = double.Parse("1234.5678", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Check your regional settings. Your decimal symbol needs to be ".".

Answer (score 0):

```
double temp = double.Parse("1234,5678");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with the above code.it works fine and prints the value `1234.5678`. I have tried it in VS2008. Probably, something to do with locale settings on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use `TryParse` instead, so you don't need to handle parsing exceptions.

```
double temp = 0;
if (double.TryParse("123.456", out temp)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Parsed temp: {0}", temp);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input value was not able to be parsed.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem when you let the text box empty then 
this error occurs  so try this one  to handle it.

> An unhandled exception of type System.FormatException occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll Additional information: Input string was not in a correct
>   format.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Txt1.Text)) {int _qty = (int)Convert.ToInt32(Txt1.Text);}
```