# Data grid view text box event handler

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am stuck into this annoying problem, i will be glad for any help.

i have a DataGridView with six columns (one is combo box and the others are text boxes).
i want to handle the textChange(text box) event and SelectedIndexChange event(combo box),
but i keep get this error and i don't know why.
**this is the error:**
***An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.***

**this is the code**

```
        dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += (sender, e) =>
            {

                if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
                {
                    ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)e.Control;
                    cb.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender2, e2) =>
                        {
                            this.client.roaming[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].country = cb.Text;
                            //dictionaries.getTypeDict()[country.Name + dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex.ToString()].Invoke(Convert.ToString(cb.Text));
                        };
                }
                else
                {
                    TextBox tb = (TextBox)e.Control;
                    tb.TextChanged += (sender1, e1) =>
                    {
                        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)
                        {
                            this.client.roaming[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].minutesIncomingAndOutcomingFromAbroadToIsrael = Convert.ToDouble(tb.Text);
                            //dictionaries.getTypeDict()[minutesIncomingAndOutcomingFromAbroadToIsrael.Name + dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex.ToString()].Invoke(Convert.ToDouble(tb.Text));
                        }
                        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 2)
                        {
                            this.client.roaming[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].minutesLocalAbroad = Convert.ToDouble(tb.Text);
                            //dictionaries.getTypeDict()[minutesLocalAbroad.Name + dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex.ToString()].Invoke(Convert.ToDouble(tb.Text));
                        }
                        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 3)
                        {
                            this.client.roaming[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].minutesAbroadToAbroad = Convert.ToDouble(tb.Text);
                            //dictionaries.getTypeDict()[minutesAbroadToAbroad.Name + dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex.ToString()].Invoke(Convert.ToDouble(tb.Text));
                        }
                        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 4)
                        {
                            this.client.roaming[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].smsFee = Convert.ToDouble(tb.Text);
                            //dictionaries.getTypeDict()[smsFee.Name + dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex.ToString()].Invoke(Convert.ToDouble(tb.Text));
                        }
                        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5)
                        {
                            this.client.roaming[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].internetFee = Convert.ToDouble(tb.Text);
                            //dictionaries.getTypeDict()[internetFee.Name + dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex.ToString()].Invoke(Convert.ToDouble(tb.Text));
                        }


                    };
                }
            };
```

Comment: Your problem is with one of those calls: Convert.ToDouble(tb.Text). Please check you inputs for that calls, you will find your error there :)

Comment: the input is numbers only.. i'm not trying to input non numeric characters.. and still, this error kip showing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

option 1: The string which you try to convert to double is not in the correct format.

option 2: described here: [Input string was not in a correct format #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275380/input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format-2)