# No action was found on the controller UmbracoApiController

Tags: c#, json, ajax, umbraco7

I am trying to do is access data from an Umbraco Api class and pass this to a javascript function. All help is appreciated in getting over the following errors. -

```
{,…}
Message
:
"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://mywebsite.local/Umbraco/Api/MapApi/GetMapMarkers/4188'."
MessageDetail
:
"No action was found on the controller 'MapApi' that matches the request."
```

The UmbracoApiController processes Google Map data and Umbraco field data that should be passed to the calling AJAX -

```
public class MapApiController :  UmbracoApiController
    {

        [HttpPost]
        public void GetMapMarkers(int nodeId)
        {
            var umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
            var contentItem = new Node(nodeId);

            // Get the map values
            var map = contentItem.GetProperty("mapLocation").Value;
            var lat = map.Split(',')[0];
            var lng = map.Split(',')[1];
            var zoom = map.Split(',')[2];

            var infoTitle = string.Empty;
            if (contentItem.GetProperty("mapLocationTitle") != null)
            {
                infoTitle = contentItem.GetProperty("mapLocationTitle").Value;
            }

            var infoText = string.Empty;
            if (contentItem.GetProperty("mapLocationInfo") != null)
            {
                infoText = contentItem.GetProperty("mapLocationInfo").Value;
            }

            string markerImageId;
            IPublishedContent markerImage;

            var mapSettings = JJWHelper.GetMapSettings();
            var markerImageUrl = mapSettings.MapPointerImage;

            if (contentItem.HasProperty("mapPointerImage"))
            {
                markerImageId = contentItem.GetProperty("mapPointerImage").Value;
                markerImage = umbracoHelper.TypedMedia(markerImageId);
                markerImageUrl = markerImage.Url;
            }

            var markers = new Marker[contentItem.ChildrenAsList.Count + 1];

            markers[0] = new Marker
            {
                MapLocation = map,
                Lat = Convert.ToDouble(lat),
                Lng = Convert.ToDouble(lng),
                Zoom = Convert.ToDouble(zoom),
                InfoTitle = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(infoTitle) ? infoTitle : " ",
                InfoText = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(infoText) ? infoText : " ",
                MarkerImageUrl = markerImageUrl
            };

            var loopCtr = 1;

            foreach (var pointer in contentItem.ChildrenAsList)
            {
                map = pointer.GetProperty("mapLocation").Value;
                lat = map.Split(',')[0];
                lng = map.Split(',')[1];
                infoTitle = pointer.GetProperty("mapLocationTitle") != null ? pointer.GetProperty("mapLocationTitle").Value : string.Empty;
                infoText = pointer.GetProperty("mapLocationInfo") != null ? pointer.GetProperty("mapLocationInfo").Value : string.Empty;
                markerImageId = pointer.GetProperty("mapPointerImage").Value;
                markerImage = umbracoHelper.TypedMedia(markerImageId);

                // Marker Image is mandatory, but issue (?) in Umbraco is allowing pointer node
                // to be published even though a pointer image has not been selected.
                // So, check that we actually have a marker image before adding it to the output array
                if (markerImage == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                markerImageUrl = markerImage.Url;
                markers[loopCtr] = new Marker
                {
                    MapLocation = map,
                    Lat = Convert.ToDouble(lat),
                    Lng = Convert.ToDouble(lng),
                    Zoom = Convert.ToDouble(zoom),
                    InfoTitle = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(infoTitle) ? infoTitle : " ",
                    InfoText = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(infoText) ? infoText : " ",
                    MarkerImageUrl = markerImageUrl
                };

                loopCtr++;
            }

            var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(markers);

            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddDays(10));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetETag(nodeId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(json);
        }
```

The AJAX call -

```
  var markers = (function () { 
            var json = null; 
            $.ajax({
                'async': false, 
                'global': false, 
                'url': "/Umbraco/Api/MapApi/GetMapMarkers/" + nodeId, 
                'dataType': "json",
                 'type': "POST",
                'success': function (data) {
                    json = data; } }); 
            return json;}
```

Comment: Try passing `nodeId` as a querystring parameter: `http://mywebsite.local/Umbraco/Api/MapApi/GetMapMarkers?nodeId=4188`

Comment: still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem was with the local server settings being set to a European setting therefore the dot was getting replaced by a comma! All fixed now and many thanks for everyone who posted!

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$.ajax({
    'async': false, 
    'global': false, 
    'url': "/Umbraco/Api/MapApi/GetMapMarkers/", 
    'dataType': "json",
    'data': { nodeId: nodeId},
    'type': "POST",
    'success': function (data) {
        json = data; } 
});
```

And in your c# code:

```
public class TestObj
{
    public int nodeId { get; set; }
}

public class MapApiController : UmbracoApiController
{

    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public void GetMapMarkers(TestObj t)
    {
        // ..
    }
}
```

Comment: Im getting this now - "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
ExceptionType
:
"System.NullReferenceException"
Message

Comment: I also had to declare the property as static to access it, but it still doesn't work -  public static int nodeId { get; set; }

Comment: It's a class (my TestObj) wrapping your nodeId property, it shouldn't have static properties. Also be extra careful to include 'data': { nodeId: nodeId}, in your javascript and not just 'data': nodeId

Comment: Removed the static references but still the same problem. Btw the controller is in a Controllers folder, do you think this has anything to do with the issue..Plus I have not defined any route as the controller is inheriting from UmbracoApiController.

Comment: I added a error in the ajax, this alerts an error         $.ajax({
                'async': false,
                'global': false,
                'url': "/Umbraco/Api/MapApi/GetMapMarkers/",
                'dataType': "json",
                'data': { nodeId: nodeId },
                'type': "POST",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert('Success');
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Failed');
                }
            });

Comment: can you edit your original post with your current code?

Comment: Im now sure its a server fault as we have moved the sites over from a UK based server to a European based one..I guesses this from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275380/input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format-2 The error is now Input string was not in a correct format at  at System.Convert.ToDouble(String value) so this is why I am assuming that its a web server regional/local setting issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you use the correct `HttpPost' attribute.

Standard it will use the `System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost` attribute and you need the `System.Web.Http.HttpPost` attribute.