# double.Parse(123.342) System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Tags: c#, format

I am trying to read a file with lines that are looking like this one:

> 2 59816.6667 22966.6667

Why do I get this **exception** when I want to run this code:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

var points = new List<Point>();

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var currentline = line.Split(' ');
    
    points.Add(new Point(
       double.Parse(currentline[1]), 
       double.Parse(currentline[2]), 
       double.Parse(currentline[0])
    ));
}

return points;
```

`Point` class:

```
class Point
{
    public Point(double x, double y, double iD)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        ID = iD;
    }

    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double ID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what's your locale? are you maybe in a region where the decimal separator is `,`? and have you evaluated if maybe in one of your lines there's invalid data?

Comment: Ok my decimal seperator in my region is ","

Comment: I tried to `for (int i = 0; i < currentline.Length; i++)
                {
                    currentline[i].Replace(".", ",");
                } ` but this doesnt work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Input string was not in a correct format #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275380/input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format-2)

Comment: Well your physical region is not relevant, but what `CultureInfo` is used by `double.Parse`. You don't provide one, so it uses `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`. Which is it? And did you debug to verify the strings contain what you expected?

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354924/how-do-i-parse-a-string-with-a-decimal-point-to-a-double as target

Comment: You may have blank lines.  You can add :  if(line.Length >0)

Answer (score 3):

Well, you have to debug. There are many posibilities (say, *invisible unicode symbols*). Let's have a `Dump` of the failed string:

```
    using System.Linq;

    ...

    private static string Dump(string value) {
      if (null == value)
        return "null";

      return "\"" + value + "\" " + 
             string.Join(" ", value.Select(c => ((int)c).ToString("x4")));
    }
```

Then let's modify the loop a bit:

```
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var currentline = line.Split(' ');

    double x, y, id;

    if (!double.TryParse(currentline[0], out id))
        throw new FormatException("{Dump(currentline[0])}  failed to be parsed as id");

    if (!double.TryParse(currentline[1], out x))
        throw new FormatException("{Dump(currentline[1])} failed to be parsed as X"); 

    if (!double.TryParse(currentline[2], out y))
        throw new FormatException("{Dump(currentline[2])} failed to be parsed as Y");

    points.Add(new Point(x, y, id));
}
```

Now you are going to have *complete information* of the string that's failed. Run the modified code once again over the file of interest, have the *dump* and see what's wrong with the string.

Answer (score 0):

Could this possibly be because one of the lines does not contain the leading digit, and instead contains a leading space, in which case currentline[0] would be empty (and throw the said exception). You could try something like the following -

```
var currentline = line.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

and also validate in each case that there are indeed 3 parts to the split (otherwise you will get an index out of range exception). Perhaps skip the loop in the first instance just to let it run through if currentline.Length < 3?